# How to add forwarding rule in Google admin routing settings using Google API?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

In admin settings in Google you can find section for `Gmail` routing. It's `Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Gmail > Routing`. There, at the bottom of the page, you can find `Email forwarding using recipient address map`.

Here, you can add rule to forward emails from one email to another. And I'm wondering, if it's possible to add this rule using Google API.

Probably, I have found it, but I am really not sure. [Here it is, from Gmail API.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/forwarding_settings) But it says only about auto-forwarding, and I guess, it's not about creating forwarding rules, like on screenshot.

So, my question is - is it possible to add forwarding rules using Google API?

[image]

Comment: What forwarding rules are you looking at add/change via the API? I think at present only the forwarding address is editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [Managing Filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings)

> Filters can automatically add or remove labels or forward emails to verified aliases based on the attributes or content of the incoming message.

```
 # create gmail api client
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    label_name = 'IMPORTANT'
    filter_content = {
        'criteria': {
            'from': 'gsuder1@workspacesamples.dev'
        },
        'action': {
            'addLabelIds': [label_name],
            'removeLabelIds': ['INBOX'],
            'forward': "forwardTo@daimto.com"
        }
    }

    # pylint: disable=E1101
    result = service.users().settings().filters().create(
        userId='me', body=filter_content).execute()
```

I haven't yet figured out how to get it to forward but the documentation says it should be able to.

i found it under action just add forward

Comment: Hi, you answer is useful, but there is one problem, every time when I execute this code I get `403 HttpError`. Do you know why it can happen? I mean, I know, this is forbidden error, but I am not pretty sure about where it comes from.

Comment: 403 means you don't have access

Comment: I do not have access to my own email?

Comment: that depends on the type of auth you are using if its a service account then you may not

Comment: This answer is not correct... filters are what you build out in the Gmail UI. You can forward email with filters, and you can build filters with the referenced API, but this is different from the Google Workspace Default Routing Rules that OP was asking about. I'm still looking for a way to create those via API.